# Is getting the entity by its key strongly consistent?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, consistency

I am making an application where the entity when created, its key is sent to the other user via notification and the user can then get the entity by lookup. Will this system be strongly consistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [datastore docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/data-consistency#query-data-consistency), lookup by key is always strongly consistent:

> Fetching an entity by key, which is also called "lookup by key", is strongly consistent.